# Community Session ID not correct when generating Conga Composer URL by APEX

Tags: apex, api, conga

We have a solution where a user (Authenticated) is logged into a Partner Community Site (.force.com) and clicks on a button (custom APEX class) to generate a URL to use conga composer (and send via Docusign).  Error is "There was an issue processing the composer request", doesn't seem to even authorize the user.  The "same" logic in a button in SF (with same user logged in) works a charm.  Only thing i can see that may differ - i think perhaps my line of enquiry is around the Session ID being generated.

** Reason for using APEX is because there is a dynamic number of signers (for Docusign) on the Document being generated.

Snippet of the code used (and i think the issue) below.
Possible place that's causing issue: 
if(system.label.Have_Session_Id == 'Y'){ newURL newURL.replaceAll('',UserInfo.getSessionId());

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> generateCongaDocument(String objAccountWrapper){
    system.debug('@#@#!'+objAccountWrapper);
    List<String> lstUrls = new List<String>();
    AccountWrapper objWrap = (AccountWrapper)JSON.deserialize(objAccountWrapper, AccountWrapper.class);
    List<Opportunity> masterOpportunity = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :objWrap.wrapAccount.Id AND Type__c = 'Master'];
    string newURL = system.label.GenerateDocumentURL;
    if(system.label.Have_Session_Id == 'Y'){
        newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<sessionId>',UserInfo.getSessionId());  
    }
    //
    newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<OrgId>',UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
    if(!masterOpportunity.isEmpty()){
        newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<OppId>',masterOpportunity[0].Id);
        newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<OppId>',masterOpportunity[0].Id);
    }
    else{
        newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<OppId>','123456789012345678');
        newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<OppId>','123456789012345678');
    }
    newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<AccId>',objWrap.wrapAccount.Id);
    // newURL = newURL.replaceAll('<AttachIds>','');
    String url = newURL;
```

This combined with a custom label generates something like this (with parts of the session Id obfuscated).

https://composer.congamerge.com/composer8/index.html?sessionId=00D90.....DSUs6e7nNlvQqyB3P...WuOKx_I&serverUrl=https://dealerportal.force.com/Soap/u/29.0/00D90000000XteAEAS&id=0066F00000oFPSRQA4&TemplateId=a116F000008PVOj&QueryId=[Applicant]a0t6F00000HaVTq?pv0=0066F00000oFPSRQA4,[Account]a0t6F00000HaVU0?pv0=0016F000027lLDtQAM&AC0=1&DS7=3&DefaultPDF=1

The session ID seems to be the problem. I think perhaps - it is to do with the .force.com passing back into Conga or something along the lines of remote sites.
First line of enquiry is, is there a way to use $API.Session_ID in the Apex code for this (and will that maybe help?)

Any advice is appreciated.
Cheers

Kaite